# How can I set the IDENTITY_INSERT option for a JDBC PreparedStatement?

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, batch-file, prepared-statement, identity-insert

I need to copy data into an MSSQLServer 2005 database table which has an identity column.

I've seen how to disable the identity column by executing

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT <table> ON
```

before the insert queries.

How can I do this when I'm using PreparedStatements to do batch inserts and I can't change the statement during the operation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

D'oh. Easy, figured it out I think.

Create a Statement first, execute SET IDENTITY_INSERT  ON. Close statement.

Create PreparedStatement, do batch stuff, close preparedstatement.

Create a Statement, execute SET IDENTITY_INSERT  OFF. Close and tidy up.

Welcome any refinements or advice on issues with this...

Comment: You should be able to do this as part of one prepared statement, you just have to separate the lines.

Answer (score 4):

@Brabster A few years late, but it may be useful to anyone who needs to do something similar. You can set `identity_insert` `on` and `off` with concatenated statements within the string you pass to `prepareStatement()`:

```
myStatement.prepareStatement("SET IDENTITY_INSERT MY_TABLE ON;INSERT INTO MY_TABLE ...;SET IDENTITY_INSERT MY_TABLE OFF");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can include `SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON/OFF` as part of the prepared statement.  This way you only execute one command from the perspective of the client.

Comment: Thanks, but how? Say I have:
INSERT INTO NAMES_TABLE (id,name) VALUES (?,?)
Which I want to use addBatch to do lots of inserts quickly. How would I modify this to do the SET... part as well?